# Is the bitbake immediate assignment behavior expected?

Tags: makefile, syntax, undefined, yocto, bitbake

Let's consider the following example in a `.bb` file:

```
X = "1"
A := "X is '${X}' and Y is '${Y}'"
B = "X is '${X}' and Y is '${Y}'"
X = "2"
Y = "3"
```

Based on the `bitbake` documentation available online and numerous other examples, I expect variables `A` and `B` to hold the following values at the end of the parsing:

```
A="X is '1' and Y is ''"
B="X is '2' and Y is '3'"
```

However, running `bitbake -e <recipe name> | grep ^A` and the same for `B` reveal that the actual values for the variables are as follows:

```
A="X is '1' and Y is '3'"
B="X is '2' and Y is '3'"
```

In other words, I was expecting that the immediate assignment operator will force a not-yet-defined variable (such as `B` at the time of parsing the `A` immediate assignment) to be left empty. However, it seems that `bitbake` chooses the last defined value for the variable. This behavior (of choosing the last defined value of the variable) is consistent also with weak and default assignments.

I also tried the same concept of immediate assignment for `GNU Make`, and it seems that `make` behaves as I expected:

```
X = 1
A := X is '$(X)' and Y is '$(Y)'
B = X is '$(X)' and Y is '$(Y)'
X = 2
Y = 3

A:
        echo "$(A)"
B:
        echo "$(B)"
```

Is there a reason for the way `bitbake` behaves when an immediate assignment contains an undefined variable? Or is it just a bug?

I tend to believe that I am missing something.

```
$ bitbake --version
BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.42.0

$ make -v
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I just realized, is it possible that the value of `A` after the immediate assignment is `X is '1' and Y is '${Y}'`, such that because `Y` could not be substituted, the entire `${Y}` string is kept in place? This way it would make sense, at the end of the parsing, to re-evaluate `A` and now, since the last value of `Y` is available, it is finally substituted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted in the comments [1] the theory that I developed while trying to explain the behavior.

Indeed, after some testing, it seems that (contrary to the documentation), `bitbake` does not substitute undefined variables, but it keeps the whole `${Y}` string in place (as per our example). This way, at the end of the parsing, the last value of `Y` is finally substituted.

To prove it, I just had to replace `${Y}` with `${Z}` in the immediate assignment to `A` line, and keep `Z` undefined. At the end of the parsing, the value of A is `"For A, X is '1' and Y is '\${Z}'"`.

Mystery solved. A bit counter-intuitive. I guess it depends on the perspective.

[1] [Is the bitbake immediate assignment behavior expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954278/is-the-bitbake-immediate-assignment-behavior-expected#comment106027891_59954278)